# Upload images to Salesforce through iOS App

Tags: ios, upload, cordova, salesforce

I am trying to upload image to **Salesforce** just like updating Leads or Accounts through my **Phonegap** iOS app. I can get the image but by googling a bit, I got to know that i have to convert the image into a BLOB.

My query is about two things:
1. How to convert the image into a blob?
2. How to upload that blob to Salesforce?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my answer under this stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829196/send-attachments-to-salesforce-native-rest-sdk-through-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blob is just a Binary Large OBject, i.e. a lump of binary data. You just want to read the file into memory and use it's content directly. There may be a need to base64 encode it, but I wouldn't have thought so.

[There's a Phonegap plugin for downloading binary data on iOS here](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/1097750723/phonegap-plugin-for-downloading-url), you can see how it uses the standard Apple SDK calls for file access, so opening them shouldn't be a problem for you.

The blog would be a field on an object, much like fields on your Accounts and Contacts, I'm not sure how you specify the size, but putting the binary data into the field shouldn't be a problem.

[There's an example of using the REST API to upload binary data (to a document) here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) — I imagine your solution would be similar to this. What Salesforce API are you using for your app? Are you using their Mobile SDK?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am using JavaScript REST API for Salesforce. I have extracted the image from the photo library and then encoded it to show on the page. Do you mean to say that I don't need to convert it into a blob? Because I tried to upload the photo just like other attributes in salesforce (by using image.src or image.imageurl) but it only stores the URL in salesforce and the picture is not upload.

Comment: Passing file name will just pass it's name as data, you actually need to pass the binary contents of the file. Phonegap should provide a way of opening that file and reading it into memory.

Comment: HI Lacey,Thanks for sharing your ideas.I have tried your above link can you give me description on the same.Im trying to upload a image to SF,But no luck.Please provide me idea/ sample for iOS Native.

Comment: Is that the app need any apex class to process the request.I posted my issue in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829196/send-attachments-to-salesforce-native-rest-sdk-through-ios

Answer (score 1):

You can attach images to Salesforce record on iPhone using Salesforce Mobile app. This requires a little customization - VF page and apex class. Once you have created the VF page  for attachment, then you need add this VF page as 'Visualforce Tab' and enable it on Salesforce Mobile Configuration. Steps to add the newly created Visualforce Tab onto Salesforce Mobile Configuration  : Setup->Mobile Administration->Salesforce Mobile->Configuration->'Select your Configuration'->Mobile Tab.

Now using this tab on Salesforce app, you can upload images as attachment.